# How to send email from a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, email

Is there a way to send an email from SharePoint by using the email addresses from a sharepoint list.

Something like sending one email to all client from a specific list and putting the addresses in the BCC field of the email.

All that in a single button that I could place in the sharepoint list header.

Answer (score 1):

You could develop something like that using a custom action, but you should be familiar with SharePoint development

Comment: Ok. There is no way of doing this using Sharepoint Designer!?? Do I have to create a custom action using the Sharepoint SDK?

Comment: In designer you could send an email from one item, I understand you need to use email addresses from all the items, right?

Comment: Then it cannot be item workflow,as those do not get access by default to all the items, just the current one